# PhpStorm emmet HTML how to auto comment closing tag

Tags: ide, phpstorm, emmet

In PHPSTORM when I type .classname or #id and hit TAB I got

```
<div class="classname"></div>
```

BUT I want it to be:

```
<div class="classname"></div><!-- .classname -->
```

Comment: `.classname` or `#id` is Emmet in action. Unfortunately Emmet cannot expand such abbreviation to your desired result. But, you should be able to build a bit more complex abbreviation which may expand as desired -- learn more here: http://docs.emmet.io/

Comment: **P.S.** If `.classname` is frequently used .. you could use **Live Template functionality** to achieve such result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In original Emmet you can use `|c` filter to produce automatic comments: http://docs.emmet.io/filters/#comment-tags-c

But I don‘t know if this feature is supported by PhpStorm since it uses its own Emmet implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to Settings|Emmet|Filters enabled by default: Comment tags=true, if you dont want to type `|c` each time.

Answer (score 0):

As Lewis mentioned, there's a preference that can be set for this. In PhpStorm 2017.3 it can be found under Settings > Editor > Emmet > HTML > Filters enabled by default. See screnshot below. [image]